# Transferring analytic expressions from Mathematica to R

Tags: export, formatting

I have a series of large-ish algebraic expressions I would like to move from MM to R. I've no doubt the way I'm doing it is rather stupid, but so far the best way i've found is to use CForm and then use a document find and replace to send all the Power() functions to exponents that R recognises.

One assumes there is an easier way to do this?

Comment: Did you try `.csv` format as a proxy?

Comment: Good tip! The problem is now I'm having trouble parsing the output in R :/ It imports it as a dataframe with factors, it seems, but despite having all the variables in the expression declared, things like eval(parse(text='fn')) just return 1 or expression(()

Comment: So currently i've gotten it to work by importing the .csv with  stringsAsFactors=F and then using eval(parse()), but this final step is quite slow (this function is called many times). It's sped up a bit by only calling eval(fn) inside the function, where fn =parse() is evaluated elsewhere - any tips on ways to speed this up or am I up against the wall of what can be done in this paradigm?

Comment: Well at the moment the call to read.csv isn't in the function that is being called repeatedly, just once, along with the parse(). it is the eval(fn) that is called a lot, presumably that is the bottleneck? I.e., parse() vs actually having the function written there (hardcoded) is the slowdown bit, so one assumes changing the import type wouldn't matter?